# Order a foreach, by the value of a calculation of values in the array

Tags: php

I have an array as follows:

```
$players = array(
    $player = array(
        'name'          => 'playername',
        'speed'         => '10',
        'agility'       => '10',
        'influence'     => '10'
    )
    etc
```

Then I calculate a $score, based on the sum of speed, agility and influence.

```
$score = $p['speed'] + $p['agility'] + $p['influence'];
```

How can I loop through my array, but order the results from highest to lowest $score?

PS-> http://pastebin.com/eUEQ5y4u

Comment: If speed, agility and influence are always a ninteger or decimal, please don't use the single quotes.

Comment: I've never seen this: `$player = array(` before INSIDE an array. I don't know if it will still work, although I assume it will. However, that won't be doing anything and you can take out the `$player =` bit. An array will just be: `$players = array( array(...), array(...) );` the `$player =` bit doesn't do anything. I'm surprised it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function to sort it by your custom algorithm:

```
function score($player) {
    return $player['speed'] + $player['agility'] + $player['influence'];
}

function cmp($a, $b) {
    $scoreA = score($a);
    $scoreB = score($b);
    if($scoreA == $scoreB) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($scoreA > $scoreB) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($players, "cmp");
```

Comment: was just writing this out. :p +1

Comment: This happens pretty often here :)

Comment: So then, after these 2 functions, I'd do foreach($players as $p) {... etc?

Comment: You don't need the `foreach` anymore. It will get sorted by score without having to use a `foreach` loop. The only problem with the above code is that you can't store the score anywhere, incase you need it again. You can put a loop in BEFORE that code which will generate scores and then use the above code to sort the array. Or just calculate scores on the fly (after sorting)... they're hardly taxing calculations.

Comment: Indeed Thomas, but it looks like Mark wants to print players based on score, so he needs `foreach` anyways. If score would be used somewhere else then I'd store it inside players array.